# VB6 using encrypt=true managing error if sql server has no encryption

Tags: error-handling, vb6, adodb

One of the software we work on offers the option to enable encryption and this will reflect in the **ENCRYPT=YES** portion of the connection string.

My connection string in my `vb6` app looks like this:

```
"Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=(local);Database=MyDevDB;Uid=MySqlUser;Pwd=myPwd;
 Encrypt=yes;OLE DB Services=-1;"
```

When my Sql server is not configured for using encryption on connection strings, from SQLCMD and SSMS, I am getting an error

> "*Cannot connect to (local) [...] A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2146893019)*".

**My question:** why am I not getting the same error when using connection in `ADO` within my `VB6` app?

VB6 lets me connect, does not encrypt of course, no warning nothing.

**Anyone knows how I can trap this in VB6?**

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the question WHY this does not occur in ADO but does occur when using some other method? Or is the question how to detect and handle this circumstance?

Comment: You mentioned this does not cause a problem when using ADO - what are you using when it does cause a problem?

Comment: Actually what I am trying to get out of my post is this: I would like the call for connection to fail when the user checked "Encrypt" in order to have the same behavior as we have with SQLCMD. Because right now, user selects "Encrypt", it connects anyway and is not encrypted.

Comment: To this date, I have not resolved my issue and am still not able to go around this.

Comment: It is weird that the connection succeeds, it is [documented to fail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/features/using-encryption-without-validation?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: I know, so weird. We ran several tests, by working with my friend sr sql developper, he was looking at sessions in sql, we could spot the old ado connection and confirm it was not encrypted. So while we still have to endure vb6 in our environment, my answer below was best thing we could come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no real answer was produced out of this call for help by myself, here is how I dealt with the absence of manageable warning or error from the db connection from ADO.

We simply removed altogether the possibility to control a form of request for encrypting db connection from VB 6 code.

Indeed, since, if anything is not working (bad certificate, encryption not possible on Sql Server, and so on) VB 6 ADO (not .net) is actually not telling us, it does not encrypt and we do not know and we do not have a clear way of knowing from caller perspective.

By moving the responsibility of connection encryption to the Sql server, we play it safe.

That is until we remove vb6 from our environment.